# PHP get Response from a requested URL

Tags: php

I am implementing a OneClick Login function. From a existing function I am getting a URL, So to get the token I should send it, when I copy paste to the browser I am getting the token. I am using php so what is the way to get the token from PHP code.

Comment: Does the token provider provide an API for you? Too vague to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) like this:

```
<?php
$response = file_get_contents("https://your-url.com/");
```

Comment: I used It but I am getting a empty. What could be the reason, but when I use that URL in browser I get the token.

Comment: @user2552863 Maybe you need cookies to make it work. What happens when you open the URL in a private browser window? Does it still work?

Comment: Yes I am getting the token.

Comment: Should We use curl for this?

Comment: Not any error message. when I use file_get_contents with url and send the request from the browser it not printing anything, but I the url without file_get_contents  and send It is printing the token.